# Is it a best practice to create and use a custom primitive component like input,select in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a lot of forms in my application and I feel that I`m replicating too much code in the input tags and select tags

```
 <div class="form-row">
     <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label required">Pre Shared Key
         <i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Pre shared key for authentication" class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
         <input class="form-control form-control-sm col-10" placeholder="Key" ShowHidePass type="password" [ngClass]="{'is-valid': form.controls.pre_shared_key.valid && (form.controls.pre_shared_key.touched || form.controls.pre_shared_key.dirty),'is-invalid':form.controls.pre_shared_key.invalid && (form.controls.pre_shared_key.touched || form.controls.pre_shared_key.dirty) }" formControlName="pre_shared_key">
     </div>
 </div>
```

especially for the toggling the classes for validation and tooltips.

I believe I can use something like

```
<custom-input formControlName="pre_shared_key" label="Pre Shared Key" placeholder="password" tooltip="some HTML or text"></custom-input>
```

Comment: I have created a library called Easy Angular https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez. It allows you to get rid of most of the boiler plate from forms applications. Here is a demo crud app https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pytks5 and a demo form showing how to include the bootstrap styles https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1wshi

Comment: Will it work with formcontrol  and moreover I have all the validations built inside reactiveForms so using a library where I should add validations again takes so much time and effort, BTW thanks for the answer and congrats on ur library its nice

Comment: All the controls implement ControlValueAccessor so it is compatible with both template and reactive forms. All the code is there on GitHub so you can have a look through at how to encapsulate control logic into easily reusable form controls.

Comment: Thank you, man! One more doubt, Just want to know, is it a good practice to reuse these custom components for all the primitive components

Comment: They are not primitive, the primitive component is an input, checkbox, select etc. These controls are composite as they are labels, controls, validation and accessibility elements. Even though they are composite, they become the primitive component of form building.